# HTML5 download attribute file name not set

Tags: jquery, html, download, filenames

I am trying to download an excel file containing data from html tables using jquery. I want to set custom file name for downloaded excel file. For this I am using `download` attribute of `<a>` tag.

User interface has a got a button for downloading excel. So I am creating an `<a>` tag within an invisible `<div>` tag and automatically clicking it in button click handler function `toExcel()`.

Here is my code.

```
var toExcel = function()
{
    var htmltable= $("#reportDiv").get(0);
    var html = htmltable.outerHTML;
    csvData = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);

    var newLink = $("<a />", {
        id : "id5",
        class : "myLink",
        href : csvData,
        text : "Export Excel",
        download:"data.xls"
    });
    $('#aDiv').append(newLink);

    $("#id5").click(function(e){
        window.location = $('#id5').attr('href');
        return true;
    });

    $('#id5').trigger('click');

}
```

With this code, download popup comes with the file but file name is again some random name and file name mentioned in download attribute does not appear. What could be wrong?

Edit: The above code works in Chrome. How can make it work it Firefox?

Comment: When you manually change `window.location` you effectively bypass the native link-click event you've just triggered. Have you tried just commenting that line out (or indeed the whole custom click handler)? It looks like it should be fine without it

Comment: When the statement `window.location = $('#id5').attr('href');` commented, the popup won't appear. Also when I click on the link itself, the download file popup with custom set file name appears. I think problem is in the code to automatically click `<a>` tag.

Comment: It's possible you're hitting a (browser-specific) security mechanism which prevents some click actions on hidden elements, but there's not enough details here to know. Could you make a MCVE? Otherwise, i can suggest trying to `.wrap` the original button with the custom `<a>` tag